# python: Run coverage on folder with tests in another folder (Eclipse PyDev)

Tags: python, eclipse, code-coverage, pydev

I have my python modules in a folder A, but my tests in a folder B.
When using coverage in Eclipse Pydev, how can I make this setup work?

Things tried:

1. Currently if I use A for the folder, got 0% coverage;
2. If I link B into the project and it sees my test classes as code classes.
3. Then I tried to copy all my tests over into A and run it again, still 0% coverage.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the python compiler to know where they are you can simply add their path to sys.path, is this what you are looking for?

[link to sys.path in python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

**EDIT:**
try using something like

```
sys.path.append(r"C:\path\to\tests")
```